# Updating value in column of array type in Parse Table

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I am new to parse data from parse.com.I am trying to update a column.The column in parse table is of array type.I am trying to add a value in array.For Example :

it is showing in data browser like this:

```
["Ado", "Wassja", "Cristi_3"]
```

And I want to add "ABC" value in this array programmatically like this:

```
["Ado", "Wassja", "Cristi_3","ABC"]
```

I have searched for this and got to know that first I need to fetch all the data of that particular row which I have to update ,then put the data in array I have fetch successfully the data for that particular row like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("UserMaster");
    query.whereEqualTo("userName",str_uname2);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> userList, ParseException e) {
            dlg.dismiss();

             if (e == null) {
                 if (userList.size()>0) {

                 for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
                     ParseObject p = userList.get(i);
                     str_dbpassword  = p.getString("password");
                     String email = p.getString("email");
                     List<ParseObject> mfollowers = p.getList("followers");
                     List<ParseObject> mfollowing =       p.getList("following");
                     ParseFile pp = (ParseFile)p.get("photo");

                     str_dbuname = p.getString("userName");

                 } 
                 Log.d("password", "Retrieved " +str_dbpassword +"<uname>"+str_dbuname);

                    }

                }
             else {

                    Alert.alertOneBtn(LoginActivity.this,"Something went wrong!");
                }   
        }
    });
```

Now I have to update data in

```
List<ParseObject> mfollowers = p.getList("followers");
```

And

```
List<ParseObject> mfollowing =  p.getList("following");
```

I don't know how to do this.Please help me.Your small clue will be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Per the docs: http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html

You can use `add`, `addUnique`, `addAll`, or `addAllUnique` to add elements to an array on a Parse Object:

```
someParseObject.add("arrayColumn", "ABC");
someParseObject.saveEventually();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have tried this ,but it gives me the exception : IllegalArgument Exception You must create this type of ParseObject using ParseObject.create()  or the proper subclass.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Fosco's answer:

```
  ParseObject parseObject = new ParseObject("YOURCLASS");
  String[] stringArray = ["Ado", "Wassja", "Cristi_3"];
  List<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(stringArray));
  if (stringArray != null)parseObject.addAll("YOURCOLUMN", stringArrayList);
```

Make sure that the security settings for YOURCLASS enable you to create columns automatically or that you have the correct types set for your columns.

I hope that completes Fosco's answer.